# Align right in a table cell with CSS

Tags: css, html-table, right-align

I have the old classic code like this,

```
<td align="right">
```

which does what it says: it right aligns the content in the cell.
So if I put two buttons in this cell, they will appear at the right site of the cell.

I was refactoring this to CSS, but there doesn't seem to be anything as right align. I see *text-align*, but is it that the same?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Use

```
text-align: right
```

> The text-align CSS property describes
>   how inline content like text is
>   aligned in its parent block element.
>   text-align does not control the
>   alignment of block elements itself,
>   only their inline content.

See

**[text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align)**

```
<td class='alnright'>text to be aligned to right</td>

<style>
    .alnright { text-align: right; }
</style>
```

Comment: is a <input type="button"> a block element because that one doesn't get aligned right?

Comment: It depends. I have a paragraph, which is block, inside a table cell (css display: table-cell), and if I give that paragraph a width of 100% it starts to respect text-align right. I assume defining a width isn't always the best thing.

Comment: I take it then, that the property `text-align` is not very well named if it applies to buttons and controls as well as text.  Perhaps this should have been called `content-align`?

Comment: Michel: set the block element to inline-block, e.g.:
td input { display:inline-block; }

Comment: or me only works float:right or good old align="right". w t f ?

Comment: oh and FYI for this to work, the table has to be width: 100%

Answer (score 15):

Don't forget about CSS3's 'nth-child' selector. If you know the index of the column you wish to align text to the right on, you can just specify

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

In cases with large tables this can save you a lot of extra markup!

here's a fiddle for ya.... https://jsfiddle.net/w16c2nad/

Comment: Great: easiest and cleanest solution I saw.

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me now is:

CSS:

```
.right {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <input id="abort" type="submit" name="abort" value="Back">
        <input id="save" type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <input id="delegate" type="submit" name="delegate" value="Delegate">
        <input id="unassign" type="submit" name="unassign" value="Unassign">
        <input id="complete" type="submit" name="complete" value="Complete">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Joysn/3u3SD/

Answer (score 8):

### How to position block elements in a `td` cell

The answers provided do a great job to right-align text in a `td` cell.

This might not be the solution when you're looking to align a block element as commented in the accepted answer. To achieve such with a block element, I have found it useful to make use of margins;

### General syntax

```css
selector {
  margin: top right bottom left;
}
```

### Justify right

```css
td > selector {
  /* there is a shorthand, TODO!  */
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}
```

### Justify center

```css
td > selector {
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

/* or the short-hand */
margin: auto;
```

### Align center

```css
td > selector {
  margin: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/johnmutuma5/tzhmbj1o/13/)

Alternatively, you could make you `td` content display `inline-block` if that's an option, but that may distort the position of its child elements.