# How to right align last two columns of a table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'd like to right align the text of last two columns of a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>H 1</th>
    <th>H 2</th>
    <th>H 3</th>
    <th>H 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='3'>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is not the same number of columns in each row and I'm not sure how to use css:nth-child to select the last two td items in each row.

Comment: There is one ugly way and that is <td align="right">X</td>

Comment: last-child selects the last, but not sure how to get the 2nd last child

Comment: possible duplicate of [align right in a table cell with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906469/align-right-in-a-table-cell-with-css)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BB9ty/

```
th:last-child,
td:last-child,
th:nth-last-child(2),
td:nth-last-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: td:nth-last-child(-n+2) does it in one go.  Thanks for the inspiration.