# Table cells right align inside row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to move a cell to the left on HTML table.
I want to use less cells in the last row and it's on the right by default.

I have this table for example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this</td>
    <td>right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to move the "this" and "right" cells to the opposite side.
I'm looking for a way with less as possible css.. preferred HTML only.

Update: I wasn't looking for answers about text/value align. `colspan` solves it somehow but still, won't call it a perfect solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [align right in a table cell with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906469/align-right-in-a-table-cell-with-css)

Comment: Can you show us a demonstration of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `td` should span two columns by using the attribute `colspan="2"`, and align the text to the right:

```css
.alignRight {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="alignRight">right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another, html only, option is to use `colspan="2"` on the "this" cell:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">this</td>
    <td>right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can only add  `align="right"` attribute

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just insert an empty cell before `<td>this</td>`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>this</td>
    <td>right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way with less as possible css.. preferred HTML only.

You can try `align` attribute of `td` with `colspan`.

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>one</th>
  <th>two</th>
  <th>three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>one</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>this</td>
  <td colspan="2" align="right">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>
    <td colspan="2">this</td>
    <td align="right">right</td>
</tr>`

colspan can be used in both cells. This will merge cell into 2.