# How to make text in a table cell locate a little right of the centre

Tags: css, javafx

I just know how to make it -fx-alignment: center-right; but it's too 'right'

Comment: text-align https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906469/align-right-in-a-table-cell-with-css

Comment: "It doesn't work": well, it does "work", it just isn't doing what you think. Most (almost all) CSS properties have corresponding Java properties they are setting, so you can check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty) to see what the properties do.